# FInd the inverse of a matrix using EJML.jar

Tags: java, ejml

Can any one help me to get the code to find the inverse of a matrix using EJML.jar

Answer (score 0):

This link https://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/downloads/list
contains the source code at this file: ejml-0.24-src.zip
Hope this works!

Comment: Today you can find the source code at Github: [https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to the API documentation. You can find all the function and classes on the following [link](http://ejml.org/javadoc/). The code below converts (internally) a matrix into its inverse value.

```
Random rand = new Random();

DenseMatrix64F a = RandomMatrices.createRandom(4,4, -1, 1, rand);

// where 4,4 is the matrix size and -1,1 the range where rand has to get 
// the random values to populate it.

invert(a); 

//The inverse gets stored in a
```

I hope it solves your question.

Comment: ```CCommonOps.invert(CDenseMatrix64F A)``` ([Source](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ejml/blob/master/main/denseC64/src/org/ejml/ops/CCommonOps.java#L499-509)) returns true if it could invert the matrix and false if it could not.

Comment: From what I understand, `invert(a);` does indeed return a boolean value. However, I would say that it represents whether the inversion has been done successfully or not. When possible, the matrix `a` still gets inverted; otherwise, a `false` boolean is returned. ([Source](http://ejml.org/javadoc/org/ejml/ops/CCommonOps.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Today you can use the following code:

```
double data[][] = new double[][]{
        { 90, 60, 90 },
        { 90, 90, 30 },
        { 60, 60, 60 }
};

SimpleMatrix m = new SimpleMatrix(data);
SimpleMatrix inverted = m.invert();

System.out.println(inverted);
```